# Не получается отправить POST запрос в виде массива на API сервер

Tags: c#, api, post, httpclient

Второй день не могу совладать с API сайта https://smmok-fb.ru/.
Дело в том, чтобы получить API ключ мне нужно отправить массив с учетными данными(mail, password) в ответе в виде строки JSON я должен получить ключ. Но в итоге никак не получается отправить запрос должным образом, прошу помочь с отправкой POST запроса.

URL API - http://smmok-fb.ru/api/getApiKey
Документация к API - https://smmok14.ru/api_docs

Класс для десерилизация JSON:

```
public class RequestSMMOK
{

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("respond")]
    public Respond[] Respond { get; set; }

}
public class Respond
{
    [JsonProperty("api_key")]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

}
```

Мой пример кода:

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "value@value.ru"),

                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","value")
            });
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var responseMessage =
                await client.PostAsync("http://smmok-fb.ru/api/getApiKey", content);

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestSMMOK>(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return result;
        }
```

Что я получаю в итоге в ответе - {"status":400,"error":"\u041d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d email"}"

Comment: Зачем вы указываете `MediaType`, если это делает за вас `FormUrlEncodedContent`? Также почему `.Result`, ведь у вас используется `async/await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не надо создавать `HttpClient` на каждый запрос.
2. `IDisposable` классы надо оборачивать в `using` или диспозить вручную.
3. `FormUrlEncodedContent` автоматически настроит Content-Type, не нужно это делать вручную
4. `.Result` в асинхронном коде - это ошибка, используйте `await`

Разберу на примере.

Объявите `HttpClient` отдельно, один раз на все время работы программы.

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Eсли вам нужен User-Agent, добавьте его тоже в конструкторе класса, один раз. Но я не уверен, что он вообще вам нужен, попробуйте сначала без него.

```csharp
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
```

Ну и сам метод.

```csharp
private async Task<T> PostAPIData<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data))
    using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        string jsonText = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonText);
    }
}
```

Вызов

```csharp
Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData.Add("email", "value@value.ru");
postData.Add("password","value");
RequestSMMOK result = await PostAPIData<RequestSMMOK>("https://smmok-fb.ru/api/getApiKey", postData);
```

---

Вот здесь еще ошибка, не нужен массив, исправьте вот так

```csharp
[JsonProperty("respond")]
public Respond Respond { get; set; }
```

Допишу сюда:

Причина ошибки была в том, что сервер хочет `HTTPS` запрос, а не `HTTP`, хотя в документации к API это не указано. Изменили ссылку на `https://`, и все заработало.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разбор!
Но, переписав полностью Ваш пример кода, так-же ответ с зарубежного SO я получаю в итоге то, что получал раннее. Ошибку, что данные не были переданы.

Comment: @FERROUSSAGE значит ошибка за пределами того кода, что вы показали, и я вам исправил. Ну это при условии, что вы в точности как я написал пробуете. Так как я не вижу остальной код, я не могу больше ничего подсказать.

Comment: Более кода нет, это весь код, который был. 
Пробую в максимальной точности, добавляя email&password в словарь

Comment: В любом случае спасибо Вам и всем остальным участникам, с другими API все работает, хотя и до этого с моим плохим кодом не было проблем с ними)

Comment: @FERROUSSAGE я нашел, как это исправить, замените "http" на "https". И сервер вам начнет нормально отвечать. Мне вот что ответил `Пользователь с указанным сочетанием логин\пароль не найден`

Comment: Да, в этом была проблема!! Спасибо большое:)

Comment: @FERROUSSAGE вы заметили, что у вас ошибка в классе данных? Я внизу ответа дописал.

Comment: Да, заметил:)
Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @FERROUSSAGE как я и предполагал, User-Agent переопределять не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если перевести коды символов utf-8 в строку, то сервер отвечает: "Не указан email". Попробуйте через Fiddler посмотреть что в реальности отправляется на сервер. Может он хочет email в другом поле, тут сложно сходу разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
По Вашему совету я посмотрел в программе Fiddler, что отправляется на сервер и увидел, что данные отправляются как надо и на выходе я получил API ключ.
Тогда я не понимаю, что я делаю не так в IDE, если я не получаю API ключа там

Comment: вот ссылка на скриншот - https://yadi.sk/i/xJZyQ5_q0xoL-Q

Comment: @FERROUSSAGE Как вы можете в Fiddler видеть успешно отправленный запрос, если в программе у вас совершенно другой ответ? Вы проверяйте не то, что через браузер или сторонний софт отправляете, а то, что отправляет ваше приложение!