# Автоматическое заполнение input type="file" C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gecko

Недавно подключил в проект geckofx 60 вместо webbrowser, т.к. он совсем перестал адекватно работать с JS.

На сайте есть форма с разнообразными полями, в том числе и полем типа file. Мне нужно вставить в него файл, находящийся в папке на локальном диске. Я чуть-чуть поправил под gecko метод, который использовал в webbrowser, тоже предварительно найденный в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687876/uploading-files-not-working-need-assistance) теме

```
//Вставляем торрент
    async Task PopulateInputFile(GeckoHtmlElement file)
    {
        file.Focus();
        string a = Properties.Settings.Default.diskString;
        // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
        var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
        {
            // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
            SendKeys.Send(a + getTorrent + "{ENTER}");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        file.Click(); // this shows up the dialog

        await sendKeyTask;

        // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }

    //вставляем постер
    async Task PopulateInputFile_poster(GeckoHtmlElement file_poster)
    {
        file_poster.Focus();

        // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
        var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
        {
            // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
            SendKeys.Send(Properties.Settings.Default.diskString  + "poster.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        file_poster.Click(); // this shows up the dialog

        await sendKeyTask;

        // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}

async Task Populate()
    {
        var elements = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        // торрент
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement file in elements)
        {
            if (file.GetAttribute("name") == "file")
            {
                file.Focus();
                await PopulateInputFile(file);
            }
        }

        //постер
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement file_poster in elements)
        {
            if (file_poster.GetAttribute("name") == "screen")
            {
                file_poster.Focus();
                await PopulateInputFile_poster(file_poster);
            }
}
            }
```

Вызываю так:

```
Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
        {

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

И если в webbrowser он работал без каких-либо нареканий, то здесь есть проблема с тем, что он не всегда фиксирует нажатие клавиши enter, в результате чего диалоговое окно остается висеть, а остальные появляются поверх него. Можно конечно, просто потом вручную нажать enter, но хотелось бы довести весь функционал до автоматизма. Отмечу, что иногда срабатывает все как надо и все поля на форме заполняются. Но это происходит редко. Чаще заполняется поле с торрентом, а остальные уже как когда.

Comment: Я вам уже задавал вопрос, когда использовали CefSharp, он тот же: на кой черт вам браузер?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чтобы не изобретать колесо и добавлять материалы на сайт через него. Наверное, можно как-то с помощью Post-запросов это сделать, но решил пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления)

Comment: Вот как раз использование браузера - это трудный и запутанный путь, хоть многим он кажется проще. Вот вы сейчас страдаете из за компонента, который не подвластен вам, написан не пойми кем и как, оно вам надо? А так бы было сразу  понятно "Ага, я отправляю тут POST запрос, сервер дает мне не тот результат, наверно я что-то забыл?!"

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я вас понял) Тогда не могли бы вы ткнуть носом в статьи или любую другую инфу по тому, как правильно эти запросы отправлять? Наверное, это будет не то же самое, когда получаешь код страницы подобным запросом...

Comment: Тут все зависит от задачи, ведь каждый сайт работает по своему. Ну а так, могу посоветовать два своих ответа ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553)), их достаточно для понимания как все это устроено и как стоит работать.

Comment: Почему `SendKeys`? Разве в `GeckoHtmlElement` нельзя просто записать данные? Например `file.InnerHtml = a + getTorrent;` или `file.Value`, или через аттрибут, смотрите, куда там путь записывается после того как вы выбрали файл. И не надо будет диалог вызывать.

Comment: Если по-простому, то выше комментарии правильные. Браузер нужен только тогда, когда вам нужно, чтобы яваскрипты работали. Для сетевого взаимодействия с сервером браузер - тяжелое излишество.

Comment: @aepot `Value`, в котором хранится путь к файлу, можно указать через `SetAttribute`, только ничего не изменится - путь не прописывается. Разве сейчас подобные манипуляции не запрещены? Я в какой-то статье видел, что раньше можно было напрямую указать данные в таком input-е, но для безопасности эту функцию убрали. А по поводу post-запросов, то сейчас сижу, ковыряюсь, но тяжко это, когда никогда с этим толком не работал)

Comment: @FaNaT_96 безопасность такого рода - фишка браузера, который вы используете. Странно было бы подобное блокировать в headless браузере, предназначенном для управления из кода, не находите? По поводу POST запросов, покажите пример запроса, я вам нарисую код. Ну или [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149173/373567).

Comment: @aepot Но почему-то `SetAttribute` не хочет устанавливать путь к файлу... По поводу Post-запросов все оказалось проще. У хостера есть API - http://api.ucoz.net/ru/manual/load/entry. Осталось только понять как его юзать, т.к. там примеры для php)

Comment: @FaNaT_96 ну вот, обычный JSON, примеров полинтернета, как тот что я показал по ссылке, только не `FormUrlContent` будет у вас, а `StringContent`, к которой будет json текст.

Comment: А, стоп, да, именно `FormUrlContent`, так что пример ровно точно в вашу тему. Практически готовенькое)

Comment: @aepot Подскажите, а как быть со строчкой `require 'uAPImodule.php';`? Если я правильно понял из документации, использование этого файла обязательно.

Comment: Вы не PHP код переписывайте, а делайте запрос сами, нужного типа, на нужный адрес, с нужными параметрами.