# Формирования URL для POST запроса

Tags: c#, api, post

Изучаю ASP.NET Web Core API. Сделал такой код:

```
[HttpPost("{post}")]
public string post_get([FromBody] string g)
{
    return g;
}
```

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос используя такой URL:

```
http://localhost:61513/weatherforecast/post?g=gfh
```

Выдаёт ошибку.

Как нужно сформировать URL для POST запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://localhost:61513/weatherforecast/post?g=gfh` - это GET запрос.

POST запрос с помощью URL строки браузера вы не сможете отправить, попробуйте скачать приложение **Fiddler** и отправлять запросы с помощью него.

А можете отправлять [POST запросы прямо в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149173/373567).

Comment: я это знаю) когда я работал с vkapi, я создал мини библиотеку с post,delete,get запросами, сейчас я и пользуюсь её

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer вопрос решен?

Comment: обращавшись к vkapi, я мог отрпавить post запросы тоже с помощью URL, наподобии такого: ```http://localhost:61513/weatherforecast/post?g=gfh```

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer вы разницу между GET и POST запросом понимаете? Или надо объяснить?

Comment: нет, вопрос не решён

Comment: я новичёк в этом, буду рад за любое объяснение)

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer GET запрос, это запрос прямо в URL `?param1=value1&param2=value2`, а POST запрос, это запрос в теле HTTP запроса, отправляемого на сервер, а не в ссылке. POST запрос может быть даже в JSON или любом другом формате, а не только как параметры GET.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо)