# Ошибка в POST запросе Binance

Tags: c#

При отправке post запроса на сайт [Binance](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) ,приходит ошибка.

> {"code":-1101,"msg":"Too many parameters; expected '6' and received '9'."}

Запрос выглядит так:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/api/v3/order", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apikey);
            request.AddQueryParameter("symbol", "CTSIBTC");
            request.AddQueryParameter("side", "BUY");
            request.AddQueryParameter("type", "STOP_LOSS_LIMIT");
            request.AddQueryParameter("timeInForce", "GTC");
            request.AddQueryParameter("quantity", quanyty);
            request.AddQueryParameter("price", price);
            request.AddQueryParameter("timestamp", timestamp);
            request.AddQueryParameter("signature", CreateSignature(request.Parameters, secret));
            request.AddQueryParameter("stopPrice", stopPrice);
            var response = client.Get(request);
```

Про ограничение параметров на гитхабе не написани ничего.Что не так?

Comment: Вы уверены, что ошибка возникает именно в этом учатке кода, а не в каком-либо другом? Как вы создаете `RestClient`?

Comment: аналогичный код при get запросе работает ,только параметров всего 3.var client = new RestClient("https://api.binance.com");

Comment: `new RestClient("https://api.binance.com");`

Comment: Все равно ругается на количество параметров

Comment: Попробуйте без `RestClient` [отправить POST запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149173/373567).

Comment: Хорошо , попробую.Спасибо

Comment: @aepot все заработало ,вместо пост запроса отправлял гет.Теперь появилась другая ошибка {"code":-1100,"msg":"Illegal characters found in parameter 'price'; legal range is '^([0-9]{1,20})(\\.[0-9]{1,20})?$'."}

Comment: У вас десятичная дробь с разделителем запятая отправляется `0,00`, а надо с точкой `0.00`. Из текста ошибки не очевидно разве?